# Chrome shortcut to open source panel directly?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, chrome-devtools-protocol

Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the Chrome source Panel directly? I found some shortcuts to open the element panel(shift+command+c) or console panel(command+option+j) but did not find one to open the Source panel, so that I can inspect and debug more quickly

Comment: So do you want Chrome to automatically open dev tools for all the tabs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is, but you can always just right-click and press inspect or just switch to the source panel after using a shortcut to view a different panel.

Answer (score 0):

`Cmd+Opt+I` will actually open the last used panel. So if **Sources** was the last panel you had opened, you can use this keyboard shortcut to directly open it while debugging.

[image]